# JQuery and Bootstrap 3 Simple to solve

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a quick question
So, my code is something like:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    //file that contains the modals
    include ('modals.php');
    <button class="openCompany">
        OPEN
    </button>
?>
//...
</body>
</html>
```

and at the very end, I've got a JS script to open a modal like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#companyModal').modal('show');
</script>
```

which works perfectly, but when I do

```
$(".openCompany").click(function () {
    $('#companyModal').modal('show');
});
```

it doesn't anymore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){    
       $(document).on("click", ".openCompany", function(e) {
       $('#companyModal').modal('show');
    });
   });
```